# Why can I not use a class constant as text domain?

Tags: plugins, translation

What makes Wordpress.org make an internationalization of a plugin approved?

I've created my first plugin and here's the main code:

https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/mastercurrency-wp/trunk/mastercurrencywp.php?rev=1374404

I am using a constant for the text domain:

```
class mastercurrencywp {
    const plugin_textdomain = 'mcwpww';
}
```

And later in the same class I use it like this:

```
$curr_desc['EUR'] = __('Euro', self::plugin_textdomain);
```

I've tested this locally and then internationalization of the plugin worked, I've also added a Swedish translation (that works on my local server) but wordpress.org states:

> ```
> This plugin is not properly prepared 
>   for localization. If you would like to 
>   translate this plugin, please contact the author.
> ```

( https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/mastercurrency-wp )

**Why?** (What is missing?)

I've just updated the plugin, so it might take some time before wordpress.org updates it statement?

Comment: `self::plugin_textdomain` is readable for a **PHP** parser only, not for the translation tool. Use a string. And the error messages aren't translated at all.

Comment: But the translation does work? With the translation tool you mean wordpress.org's translation tool? The error messages .. yes thanks I did miss those.

Comment: @toscho - I've updated, but it still get the same statement from wordpress.org

Comment: I think I've understand the actual issue now! I don't understand how I could miss this: "Do not use variable names for the text domain portion of a gettext function.  Do not do this as a shortcut: __( ‘Translate me.’ , $text_domain );".

Comment: @toscho - sorry. Somehow I managed to misunderstand your answer. Please put that as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: I'll do. First, I have to edit your question. :)

Comment: here is the link of very useful article [Internationalization: You’re probably doing it wrong](http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value of a constant or variable can be evaluated by a PHP parser only. The tool that is used to [extract the translatable strings](http://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/tools/i18n/extract.php) is *written* in PHP, but is just a string parser. It doesn't *run* your code, because that would be too slow and error prone.

Here is an example for how complex that could be:

```
interface FooTranslate
{
    const TEXT_DOMAIN = 'foo';
}
interface BarTranslate extends FooTranslate {}

class FooBar implements BarTranslate
{
    public function greeting()
    {
        _e( 'hello!', self::TEXT_DOMAIN );
    }
}

(new FooBar)->greeting();
```

Now find the correct string value for the text domain without *executing* PHP. Difficult.

---

You have to use a simple string for all calls to the translation functions.

The [developer handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/) is telling us that very clearly, unfortunately in the style of an error message and with wrong quotation marks:

> Do not use variable names for the text domain portion of a gettext function.  Do not do this as a shortcut: `__( ‘Translate me.’ , $text_domain );`

On a second note: Please **do not load your translation files on `init`**. This is expensive: These files are now loaded on every call to AJAX requests, comment submissions and every other file that might not even be related to your plugin. Check the current request context before you are asking WordPress to include a file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There were actually one more issue. The textdomain should be the slug of the plugin. It didn't work to place the name of the file (mastercurrency.php) as the documentation stated (https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/ ). I had to change the textdomain to mastercurrency-wp for the translation tool to work.

Comment: I've read around and seeing lot of sites that says I should load translation files on init.Here's an example: http://geertdedeckere.be/article/loading-wordpress-language-files-the-right-way . Here's another one:https://ulrich.pogson.ch/load-theme-plugin-translations Are they they incorrect?

Comment: Yes, if they are recommending to load those files without respect to the request context, they are wrong.

Comment: Should I use a hook at or just load it at construct() ?

Comment: Always wait for the proper hook. You _can_ invoke a constructor on a hook too, so this not really mutually exclusive choice.

Comment: that doesn't make sense at all. You say the others are incorrect and I can see what you mean, but I'm not able to understand what to do instead.

Comment: From Codex: "load_plugin_textdomain calls should be made during init, otherwise users cannot hook into it." - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init

Comment: That's nonsense.